# jquery add class only if exists text

Tags: jquery

this one is a bit complicated ?
i have a bunch of class ".product-grid .item-box "

and i want to add a class **only** for those who as  the text exists  "NEWprod" in the description 
the description  class name is ".product-grid .product-item .description"

any why to do it with jquery?

i tried

```
$(document).ready(function () {

if ($(' div.description:contains("חדש1")').length > 0) {
    $(".product-grid .item-box").addClass("newprod");
}

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to target the specific item box, the example you shared targets them all. Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('div.description:contains("חדש1")').each(function(){
    $(this).closest(".product-grid").find(".item-box").addClass("newprod");
  });

});
```

I am assuming the following HTML, since I had to guess:

```
<div class="product-grid">
  <div class="item-box">...</div>
  <div class="description">....</div>
</div>
```

---

Update: After thinking about it, the HTML probably looks like this:

```
<div class="product-grid">
  <div class="item-box">
      <div class="description">....</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

and if that is the case, use this code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('div.description:contains("חדש1")').each(function(){
    $(this).closest(".item-box").addClass("newprod");
  });

});
```

Comment: i tried but it still not working because it is adding the .newprod to all of the .item-box in page  and not only to the one  with the text! stil need help :(

Comment: Does the HTML match? If not, please provide a sample.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear but I think this can help you.

```
if ($(' div.description').hasClass('חדש')) {
    $(".product-grid .item-box").addClass("newprod");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(' div.description:contains("חדש1")').each(function() {
    $(this).parent().find(".item-box").addClass("newprod");
});
```